# Android Photo/Media/File Permission

Tags: file-permissions

I've downloaded an android application, then the application asked about this permission:
[image]

I've searched for it but there isn't any efficient answer. Does it mean that the application is able to send all of my files through the Internet?

Answer (score 1):

Google has mentioned following info about this permission [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/6014972):

> ### Photos/Media/Files
>
> An app can use files or data stored on your device. Photos/Media/Files access may include the ability to:
>
> - Read the contents of your USB storage (example: SD card)
> - Modify or delete the contents of your USB storage
> - Format external storage
> - Mount or unmount external storage

---

> [Does] it mean that the application is able to send all of my files [through] the Internet?

Nothing can be concretely  said solely based upon the data mentioned in the question. However, if the said permission is the only permission requested from the app, then the answer would be **NO**, the app can't send any of your file through the internet.

This may be of your interest: [Photos/Media/Files and Full Network Access](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/101392/photos-media-files-and-full-network-access)

Comment: Actually the application also asks for Network and Internet permissions, so it seems that sending files is possible.

Comment: Well, in that case, you should add that info into your question, and then please make relevant changes into my answer as well. :)